# How to figure out the largest Fibonacci number that my system can represent?

Tags: java, fibonacci

I'm asked to figure out the largest Fibonacci number that can be displayed on my system. Any idea how to go about that?

Comment: short answer: **you cannot.** long answer: **can you determine the largest number?**

Comment: What do you mean by "largest fibonacci number that can be displayed on my system"? Can you specify the upper bound more clearly?

Comment: Fibonacci can work only with Integers. Thus i would suggest you pass as an argument Integer.MAX_VALUE (2^31 - 1) or change your method's signature and pass Long.MAX_VALUE(2^63 - 1). In theory this should be the largest number your system can calculate.

Comment: @nikkatsa BigInteger will let you go well over the limit of Long.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: If you employ arbitrary-precision arithmetic, you can perform calculations on numbers larger than **int** and **long**. You can calculate a Fibonacci number that fills the entire screen. Then, the size of the largest displayable number depends on the screen resolution and font size.

Comment: @nikkatsa, the Integer type can only go to Integer.MAX_VALUE, but that does not mean you can't use other type (such as BigDecimal!), or even implement your own natural number type. The question is vague, because what does "display" mean here? what about the width of the screen, and the smallest legible font size? that puts a maximum limit on the number of characters you can print on screen, and thus a limit on the largest fibonacci number!

Comment: @nikkatsa why specifically these expressions  (2^31 -1) and (2^63-1) ?

Comment: @KareemMesbah ^ means power.

Comment: @GoblinAlchemist should should I keep looping or generating a random numbers till I get the fibonacci number that will fill my screen of numbers ? and how can I determine whether that a specific number fills my screen ?

Comment: @nikkatsa I know that ^ means power I was asking why did you say (2^31 -1) and (2^63 -1) specifically ?

Comment: @KareemMesbah the expressions determine maximum integer or long number in a system based on the Java API. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

Comment: @KareemMesbah, I just wanted to show that your question should be more specific. You must define what you mean under "the largest displayable number". How do you determine whether a number is displayable? How to distinguish between displayable and non-displayable numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> determine the largest fibonacci number that can be displayed on my system

For that you need to use BigInteger

Run this until your application stops because you have run out of resources.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
    BigInteger b = BigInteger.ONE;
    String last = null;
    try {
        for (long count = 1; ; count++) {
            BigInteger c = a.add(b);
            last = c.toString();
            a = b;
            b = c;
            if (count % 10000 == 0)
                System.out.println("... " + count);
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("The largest value which was calculated was");
        System.out.println(last);
    }
}
```

I would try it with a low amount of memory first e.g. `-mx16m`

Update: Even with a limit of 16 MB, it has calculated 13K terms and still running.

Comment: +1 for being the only solution that actually addresses the fact that the question didn't ask for the largest Java Integer Fibonacci value

Comment: I think this is somehow an advanced piece of code for sorry I can't understand what's going on when I run this. Herminator comment made me a little confusing by realizing that the largest fibonacci number that can be displayed on my system is not (max int)th fibonacci number. please can you provide me with some additional resources to understand this ?

Comment: @Herminator, I thought it was implied. As has been discussed earlier in the thread, the question makes the most sense if you assume that it meant the max int/long values. Otherwise, what is the metric for "largest number that can be displayed on my system"? That statement can be applied to max int/long values, but not satisfactorily to any other metric. For instance, this answer restricts it by available memory - what's the basis for choosing that metric? After all, it could be extended to store intermediate results. (This would also be more practical using a symbolic solution like @assylias)

Comment: @KareemMesbah, On a closely related note, it would help if you clarified your question. What, precisely, do you mean by the "largest number that can be displayed on my system?" And what is the reason that you need this?

Comment: @Kiyura shortly I am trying to solve an exercise in a book which I study from section a from the exercise asked me to Write a method fibonacci( n ) that calculates the nth Fibonacci number. then asked me to Determine the largest Fibonacci number that can be displayed on your system. this is the exact question.

Comment: @KareemMesbah, In the context of the preceding question -- writing a "normal" Fibonacci procedure using native int/long types -- it's likely that it meant within the size limitations of those types. Don't overthink it! The book could probably use some clarification, too.

Comment: @KareemMesbah The largest number you can display on your screen isn't limited by your screen but a limit of the highest representable value.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I guessed that, but I don't know how to get the largest fibonacci number that can be displayed on my system by using more simple techniques which should be somehow like the code I posted in my question. so any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5):

The largest `int` fibonacci number in Java:

```
public class FibonacciTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.printf("%d\n", largestFibonacciInt());
    }

    public static int largestFibonacciInt()
    {
        int temp;
        int last = 1;
        int fib = 1;

        while (fib + last > fib) {
            temp = fib;
            fib += last;
            last = temp;
        }

        return fib;
    }
}
```

You can also do this with `long`, by simply replacing all the occurrences of `int`.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to find the largest fibonacci number that can be represented as an `int` in Java, you could simply calculate the next number until it overflows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Largest integer Fibonacci number: " + maxFibonacci());
}

public static int maxFibonacci() {
    int n = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int fib = 1;
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        int last = fib;
        fib += temp;
        if (fib < 0) return last; //overflow, we are done
        temp = last;
    }
    return 0; //unreachable
}
```

Now obviously, your system is able to calculate a much higher number, for example by using a BigInteger. In that scenario, the limit will be one of:

- processing time
- available memory or
- (if you have a lot of memory and a lot of time) limitation of BigInteger which is backed by an `int[]` and therefore limited to an array size of 2^31.

---

Finally, it is probably worth saying that your problem can be better solved mathematically.

If you need to find the largest Fibonacci number that is less than a certain number `N`, you can also use [the rounding calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Computation_by_rounding):

```
phi^n / sqrt(5) < N
```

which gives you:

```
n < log(N x sqrt(5)) / log(phi)
```

Then you can calculate the right hand side part for your chosen `N`, round it down to find `n`, and calculate the corresponding Fibonacci number with:

```
F(n) = floor(phi^n / sqrt(5))
```

Comment: Um, this doesn't find the Fibonacci number with the value just below Integer.MAX-VALUE, it finds. the Integer.MAX_VALUE'th Fibonacci number.

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed `if (fib < 0)`. Still, seems like too much work.

Comment: @Kiyura It loops until a fibonacci number that is higher than Integer.MAX_VALUE is found (which overflows), and returns the previous one.

Comment: My solution doesn't require knowing Integer.MAX_VALUE :)

Comment: @Kiyura Yes - I started from the original code - your solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate for 100K or even more.
For the 100k in my computer, it only takes 1.4s to calculate the result.

```
private static final Map<Integer, BigInteger> fbNumbers = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    fbNumbers.put(0, BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    fbNumbers.put(1, BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(fbCalculationForBigNumbers(100000));
    System.out.println(String.format("%d ms", System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
}

private static BigInteger fbCalculationForBigNumbers(int num) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, num).mapToObj(i -> fbCalculation(i)).max((x,y) -> x.compareTo(y)).get();
}

private static BigInteger fbCalculation(int num) {

    if (fbNumbers.containsKey(num)) {
        return fbNumbers.get(num);
    }

    BigInteger result = fbCalculation(num - 1).add(fbCalculation(num - 2));
    fbNumbers.put(num, result);
    return result;

}
```